# Troubleshooting a Persistent Java Thread Issue

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm encountering issues with the threading in my project. As you can observe in the image, I'm attempting to illustrate all the steps involved in reaching the desired number through a binary search. However, it appears to skip directly to the final part, even though I've allocated 5 seconds for each step.

```
else if (e.getSource() == startButton){
                colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[0]), Color.BLUE);
                colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[arrayLabel.length-1]), Color.BLUE);
                BinarySearchAlgorithm(arrayLabel, 0, arrayLabel.length-1, 1);
}

public void BinarySearchAlgorithm(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
        int auxl=l, auxr=r, auxm;
        while (l <= r) {
            int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[m]), Color.BLUE);
            if (arr[m] == x) {
                colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[m]), Color.GREEN);
                return;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
            if (arr[m] < x) {
                l = m + 1;
                colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[auxl]), Color.BLACK);
                colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[l]), Color.BLUE);
            }
            else {
                r = m - 1;
                colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[auxr]), Color.BLACK);
                colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[r]), Color.BLUE);
            }
            colorLabel(Integer.toString(arrayLabel[m]), Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what kind of this problem?

Comment: Many similar questions on SO. Not a good idea to `sleep` on the _Event Dispatch Thread_ (EDT). Consider using a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: NB: don't use `System.out.println(ex.toString());` but use `ex.printStackTrace();` instead - but only (!) for developing and debugging purposes. *Never* use this in production code. (And use the `printStackTrace` also because it's spotted easier by tools and humans to be removed before going with code in production.)

Comment: How is this exactly related to threading? It looks more to me that you want to find a way where you ensure that no parallel processing is done, but you want to serialize a calculation (one step of boolean search) with its visual representation _and_ slow it down in a way so a human can see changes.
So you actually should look how to ensure that your changes are drawn, before you send your thread to sleep.
Or find a different way of visual presentation (maybe a kind of tree or table where each row represents a step in the search) where the steps are traceable even if they are drawn "at once".